# Missing kernel log messages from a guest Linux OS running inside VMWare Workstation

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

In the Linux kernel `printk()` is supposed to flush the written message immediately (i.e. messages are not buffered). Which means in the case of crash you can still see anything written before the kernel crashed. At least that is what should happen if you are running the kernel on a physical machine.

However, when running Linux inside a vmware vm. Many lines before the kernel crash are lost. Approximately 100~150 lines. Is there anyway to force vmware not to cache the messages and log them as soon as they are written to the log?

The behavior I am seeing is very consistent. I used VMWare workstation 9, 10, and 11. Different versions of Linux kernel. And I used Windows 7, 8, and 8.1 as host OS.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you looking at the log messages? Remember that, if the kernel is panicing, your system log daemon cannot write the log messages to disk after the panic, because the system is halted.

Comment: The log messages are placed in places that occurs BEFORE where the kernel should panic. I am looking at the messages using regular text editor (e.g. gedit), and I am examining the file /var/log/syslog and friends (e.g. kern.log). That is after the guest is rebooted.